# how to align text to the left?

Tags: python, tkinter

please help to fix the script.

```
from tkinter import *
colors = ['red',  'white',  'blue']

def packbox(root):
    Label(root, text='Pack').pack()
    for color in colors:
        row = Frame(root)
        lab = Label(row, text=color, relief=RIDGE,  width=25)
        ent = Entry(row, bg=color,   relief=SUNKEN, width=50)
        row.pack(side=TOP,   expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        lab.pack(side=LEFT,  expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

root = Tk()
packbox(root)
mainloop()
```

I would like to align the text in the Label widget on the left edge

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this

```
Label(root, text='Pack', anchor='w').pack(fill='both')
```

Comment: thanks. so works 
lab = Label(row, text=color, relief=RIDGE,  width=25, anchor='w')

Comment: Some explanation as to why this works would be better instead of just the expression.

Comment: I got the error message `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!frame.!frame.!frame.!frame which already has slaves managed by pack`, so I removed the `.pack()`, and it still works.

Answer (score 13):

Anchors are used to define where text is positioned relative to a reference point.

Here is list of possible constants, which can be used for Anchor attribute.

```
NW

N

NE

W

CENTER

E

SW

S

SE
```

Comment: I don't know about the others, but CENTER definitely has to be in lower case - just tried it.

Comment: Error code says the same:

_tkinter.TclError: bad anchor "W": must be n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw, or center

Comment: Ajay might be mixing it up with grid(sticky), which does want uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

The following opens a new window with text for each of the buttons whitebutton, redbutton and
bluebutton when they are pressed, the buttons are all aligned LEFT, and in each button's method
there is an additional button named "Close window" that closes the new window that is opened with each button click.

```
from Tkinter import*

import Tkinter as tk


class Packbox(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)


        bottomframe = Frame(root)


        bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )


        # Initialize buttons redbutton, whitebutton and bluebutton



        whitebutton = Button(self, text="Red", fg="red", command=self.white_button)
        whitebutton.pack( side = LEFT)

        redbutton = Button(self, text="white", fg="white",  command=self.red_button)
        redbutton.pack( side = LEFT )



        bluebutton = Button(self, text="Blue", fg="blue", command=self.blue_button)
        bluebutton.pack( side = LEFT )

        self.white_button()
        self.red_button()
        self.blue_button()

        # Define each buttons method, for example,  white_button() is whitebutton's method, which
        # is called by command=self.white_button


    def white_button(self):

        self.top = tk.Toplevel(self)

        # Creates new button that closes the new window that is opened when one of the color buttons
        # are pressed. 
        button = tk.Button(self.top, text="Close window", command=self.top.destroy)

        # prints the text in the new window that's opened with the whitebutton is pressed

        label = tk.Label(self.top, wraplength=200,text="This prints white button txt")


        label.pack(fill="x")
        button.pack()


    def red_button(self):

        self.top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        button = tk.Button(self.top, text="Close window", command=self.top.destroy)

        label = tk.Label(self.top, wraplength=200,text="This prints red button txt")

        label.pack(fill="x")
        button.pack()




    def blue_button(self):

        self.top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        button = tk.Button(self.top, text="Close window", command=self.top.destroy)

        label = tk.Label(self.top, wraplength=200,text="This prints blue button txt")


        label.pack(fill="x")

        button.pack()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Packbox(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```